# bash script - sqlite how to insert variables with space

Tags: bash, sqlite, whitespace

How to insert variables that has space into sqlite?

I have this line:

```
sqlite3 testsql.sqlite "INSERT INTO NormalTable (value1,value2) VALUES ('new word','ny ord')";
```

and I got only "new" and "ny" inserted.

EDIT 1:

I use this to print out values, but I get only new -> ny:

## Getting my data

```
LIST=`sqlite3 testsql.sqlite "SELECT * FROM NormalTable WHERE 1"`;

#For each row
for ROW in $LIST; do
    ID=`echo $ROW | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[1]}'`
    Name=`echo $ROW | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[2]}'`
    Value=`echo $ROW | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3]}'`
    #Printing my data
    echo -e "\e[4m$Id\e[m) "$Name" -> " $Value;
done
```

Comment: I would expect that to work.

Comment: Ah, ok, how do you print out values for each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately,

```
LIST=`sqlite3 testsql.sqlite "SELECT * FROM NormalTable WHERE 1"`;
for ROW in $LIST; do
...
done
```

captures the output and splits at any white space by default and not at newlines only.
You can achieve what you want by modifying the `IFS` shell variable, but this might prove cumbersome.

You can use a `while read` loop instead

```
sqlite3 testsql.sqlite "SELECT * FROM NormalTable WHERE 1" | while read ROW; do
...
done
```

This will read at newline boundary and work as you expected.

Comment: @wagashi Please see modified answer.